# Re-positioning the mat-form and mat-select label

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to move the angular mat form and select label out of the border when clicked but it's not working. Is there any way to do that ?[p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpVoa.png)

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Subject</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [value]="subject">
                    {{ subject }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-icon class="icon-suffix" matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>

Comment: <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label style="margin-left: 20px;">Search Student</mat-label>
            <input style="margin-left: 8px;" matInput placeholder="Search Student" />
            <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you mean here. Do you have a jsFiddle we could see? Do you mean move the chevron and label out of the border of the select element?

Comment: i have posted the pic. Click on p hyperlink at the end of the questiom

Comment: post your code on the post with correct indentation please